# Angularjs php node apache2

Tags: php, angularjs, apache, node.js

Comecei a desenvolver em `Node.js` utilizando os frameworks `Express` e `Angular` em quando precisei de tutoriais observei que em alguns é utilizado o `Angular` junto `PHP` para fazer requisições em banco.

Minha dúvida é: em qual servidor exatamente eu executo a aplicação com os scripts em `PHP`?

Pensei em algo como criar um projeto com angular no path do *host* mas duvido que isto seja a solução. Por favor alguém me explique exatamente como será a estrutura do projeto utilizando `PHP` e `Angular` e em que servidor irei rodar.

Comment: Podes explicar o que queres fazer? Precisas de PHP? Se não o melhor é correr tudo em Node.

Answer (score 1):

Hoje NodeJS faz tudo que o PHP faz e mais um pouco... Se quiser usar realmente o PHP você vai usar o APACHE pra subir aplicação.

Se optar por NODE tente fazer algo usando SAILS (Framework) ou então usando a estrutura MEAN (Mongo Express Angular e NodeJS).

Se optar por PHP, utilize alguma framework como CodeIgniter ou Laravel